# syntax error using mongo-db updateMany query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I can't figure this one out. Trying to add a field in all documents where a field matches the expression.

Am trying various combinations of the below updateMany query:

```
db.fixtures.updateMany({"competition": "League Division 1"}, $set{"comp_id":"5c65d916456b5d0e207778ac"})
```

Keep getting this error:

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list @(shell):1:65

Can someone please put me out of my misery and tell me what I'm doing wrong so I can enjoy the rest of my Sunday!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the syntax wrong...

```
db.fixtures.updateMany({"competition": "League Division 1"}, {"set":{"comp_id":"5c65d916456b5d0e207778ac"}})
```

Comment: Thank you!

I followed the syntax given in the docs here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/

Comment: You don’t have to include the quotation marks but your set operator must be enclosed in an object (curly braces and colon)